# Node.js in android-studio

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio

I am walking through the Node.js example at https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/getting-started-android and I keep coming up with the error "ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'jniLibs' for source set 'main' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet."

My libnode folder is at the same level as the build.gradle file:  app/libnode and app/build.gradle

I am using android-studio for the first time also so am way out of my depth here :)

Here is my build.gradle file which is where the error is occuring:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

// If you want Gradle to package prebuilt native libraries
// with your APK, modify the default source set configuration
// to include the directory of your prebuilt .so files as follows.
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs './libnode/bin/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you check by putting sourceSet block inside android block?  Hope this will solve your issue. For more details visit here: https://blog.csdn.net/changcsw/article/details/80020851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sourceSets block should be inside your android block

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }

    // If you want Gradle to package prebuilt native libraries
    // with your APK, modify the default source set configuration
    // to include the directory of your prebuilt .so files as follows.
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs './libnode/bin/'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it.  I now have new errors which is refreshing.  Thanks so much for this advice.  So simple but quite unclear in the documentation.  Again, thank you.